# Need php regex between 2 sets of chars

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression for php that outputs everything between `<!--:en-->` and `<!--:-->`.
So for `<!--:en-->STRING<!--:-->` it would output just `STRING`.

EDIT: oh and the following `<!--:-->` nedds to be the first one after `<!--:en-->` becouse there are more in the text..

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?  Show us your code - and we'll point out what needs to change.

Comment: i haven't got any code since i suck at regex :)

Comment: To add code, just select text and click icon with parenthies or ctrl+k on windows, I have fixed this for you

Comment: I think he means that he hasn't written anything - and wants us to do the work for him.

Comment: @Aleks G - I think that this is a perfectly valid question.  The OP is asking for help on one aspect (regex for this condition) and not writing a whole translation system for some website... or building the next Facebook... or doing their homework for them.

Comment: It's a valid question, but I think some take issue with the tone. No question is expressly asked. OP said, "I need..." with an expectation of it being given, rather than "How do I...?" Otherwise, yeah, it's perfectly fine.

Comment: oh.. then sorry about "the tone"..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one you want is actually not too complicated:

```
/<!--:en-->(.*?)<!--:-->/gi
```

Your matches will be in capture group 1.

Explanation:

The `.*?` is a lazy quantifier. Basically, it means "keep matching until you find the shortest string that will still fit this pattern." This is what will cause the matching to stop at the first instance of `<!--:-->`, rather than sucking up everything until the last `<!--:-->` in the document.

Usage is something like `preg_match("/<!--:en-->(.*?)<!--:-->/gi", $input)` if I recall my PHP correctly.

Answer (score -1):

If you have just that input

```
$input  = '<!--:en-->STRING<!--:-->';
```

You can try with

```
$output = strip_tags($input);
```

Comment: yeah, that wont work couse i got < !--:en-- > and < !--:de-- >, so it would strip them all out...

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
^< !--:en-- >(.*)< !--:-- >$
```

I don't think any of the other characters need to be escaped.

Comment: OP didn't specify that the string is the entire line; in fact he specifically said that there were more than one of these patterns in the input. Your pattern is wrong in at least three ways: requiring the entire string to match, requiring spaces inside the tags, and using the greedy `.*` which will consume all the way to the last closing tag as one match, even without the `^$`.

Answer (score -3):

```
<!--:en--\b[^>]*>(.*?)<!--:-->
```

This will match the things between your tags. This will break if you nest your tags, but you didnt say you were doing that :)

Comment: This won't work. First of all, there's no word boundary after `-` unless it's immediately followed by a word character (something matching `\w+`. Second, you have an extraneous `/` inside the second tag. There's no `/` in the requirements.

Comment: Removed the extra forward slash, was just used to html tags. This works and matches all text between html tags, it should work fine searching these too.

Also OP, post the code you are using so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: It will still fail if `<!--:en--` doesn't have at least one word character before the `>`. I think `\b` might not do what you think it does...